# Filtaquilla Thunderbird Plugin, regex issue

Tags: thunderbird

Im using Thunderbird with the FiltaQuilla plugin.

My Regex rules looks like this:
WordOne|WordTwo|WordThree|A whole string

Problem is that it triggers on the word 'whole'.

Anyone knows how I can write the regex so that it matches the entire string?

I have tried to encapsulate the string with " and ', that doesnt work.

Comment: Is the expression shown the actual expression being used? Sometimes the details are important. If you don't want to share the original expression, try to make a test case you can show.